# Find label name which doesn't contain input immediately from a table

Tags: groovy

I am having a table which contains multiple td/tr. 
            My problem is label which i want to get doesn't contains input immediately neither that label has any attributes property.

I want to get "Countries of Permanent Residence" and Dates which are in span but doesn't have any properties that span is in div that too doesn't contains any property.

I tried with

```
formElement[input[name="icims_gh_Permanent_Country_Residence"]]
```

But don't know how to get associate label.

Html looks like:

```
         <div style="margin:0px">
            <table style="width:100%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                  <div style="margin:0px">
                    <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px"> Countries of Permanent Residence (list all) </span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                  <div style="margin:0px">
                    <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px"> Dates </span>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" valign="top">
                  <div style="margin:0px">
                    <div>
                      <input type="hidden" name="icims_gh_Permanent_Country_Residence" value="1">
                      <a name="0.1_icims_ga_Permanent_Country_Residence"></a>
                      <div>
                        <table style="width:100%;border:0px">
                          <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <table style="width:100%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td valign="top">
                                    <div style="margin:0px">
                                      <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px">
                                        <input type="text" name="icims_0_permResidenceCountry"> </span>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                  <td valign="top">
                                    <div style="margin:0px">
                                      <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px">
                                        <input type="text" name="icims_0_permResidenceCountryDates"> </span>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain by what means, you try to read that html?  is it the xmlslurper? Add a complete working example.

Comment: I am using jsoup Extractor to extract html. Ex: we have a html content like <option title="Dishonorable" value="Dishonorable">Dishonorable</option> Suppose if I want to extract Dishonorable then I will write like formElement[option[title="Dishonorable"]].